Replacing file text with github secret values
I have a github project that contains a config file with some settings that are supposed to be replaced on building
#some_config_file
some_setting=foo
url=http://<secret_url>:8080/path
username=<secret_user>
password=<secret_pass>
other_setting=bar

The <secret_url>, <secret_user> and <secret_pass> values are supposed to be replaced with proper values inside a Github action:
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
...
    - name: Update Secret URL
      run: sed -i 's/<secret_url>/${{secrets.SECRET_URL}}/' some_config_file
    - name: Update Secret Username
      run: sed -i 's/<secret_user>/${{secrets.SECRET_USER}}/' some_config_file
    - name: Update Secret Username
      run: sed -i 's/<secret_pass>/${{secrets.SECRET_USER}}/' some_config_file
...

This works for simple strings, but when it comes to the password which is randomly generated with several special characters, it often fails or otherwise breaks in unexpected ways or outputs an incorrect value for the password
eg. setting the password to
just$Some.p*s&w[0R\d

or
$ome_|n&3cureV@l*e.\o/

completely breaks it.
The password is provided, we cannot change it ourselves and may or may not get changed to contain other special characters.
How can I do this replacement while still catering for any special characters that could be part of the password?

The problem is, sed is trying to interpret the special characters as part of the replacement string. What you need is a "dumb substitution". Here is a one liner that should work to replace the <secret_pass> string with your password:
bash -c 'replace_pw () { pw="$1"; while read line; do var=$(echo $line | cut -d= -f1); value=$(echo $line | cut -d= -f2); if [ "$value" == "<secret_pass>" ]; then echo "$var=$pw"; else echo "$var=$value"; fi; done }; cat some_config_file | replace_pw '\''${{secrets.SECRET_PASSWORD}}'\' > junk.$$; mv junk.$$ some_config_file

As a side note, I noticed that you have:
run: sed -i 's/<secret_pass>/${{secrets.SECRET_USER}}/' some_config_file

I assume you meant to use something else besides secrets.SECRET_USER. I used secrets.SECRET_PASSWORD in my example above.

This worked, though just a few additions I made
-Blank lines or other lines that do not contain = will be changed to = . A simple check to see if the line does not contain - and echoing the line as-is , otherwise doing the rest of the function.
-The last line does not get added to the newly created file due to cat not adding one. Simply changing cat some_config_file to (echo ; cat some_config_file) fixes that
